# Ajax TabControl loading slowly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am having an ajax tab control in my page each tab contains some 15 controls. My tab container has some 10 tabs.

Its take some time load in my web page. Please let me know how to reduce the page loading time. or anyother suggestions

Since the number of database calls are less.

The controls are read only displays.

Comment: Just to clarify ? 10 tabs * 15 controls per tab == 150 controls... being simultaneously loaded on to one page ?

Are they interactive forms or just read-only displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the amount of ViewState being created and the execution time of your database calls needed to create the controls. Use the **page trace option** to do this.

```
<% @Page ... Trace="True" ... %>
```

This should show you where the executing time goes and which controls a the largest in means of html-size.

In your specific case (Tabstrip) it could be a good strategy leveraging the page by implementing the content of some tabs (tabs which are not always opened by the user) **as dedicated pages loaded in an iframe on demand** - activated by a Javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other comment on viewstate try to handle it out of the page.  What I mean by this is write your own viewstate handler to store it on the server side so that you don't send it to the client on every roundtrip. If you are unsure of how to do this please message me or reply and I can send you some code that will help you handle this in an ajax environment.

If those are options then you might want to consider making the contents of each tab invisible until the user clicks on the tab.  You would need to handle the postback from each click and update the content, buy you would be sending less content at a time and this might make more sense in some scenarios?  Do you have a public version of the page that I can see?

Andrew